# viewDidUnload called after dealloc?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning, viewdidunload

When I'm debugging my iPad app, I found because of low memory, some view controllers' `viewDidUnload` got called. But seconds later, their `viewDidLoad` are called. And then again because of low memory, `viewDidUnload`, then `viewDidLoad` again. This is like file system keep swapping files due to low memory.

Is it supposed to be like this, or I have done something wrong?

Then I wanna release the view controller to get rid of this. But sometimes `viewDidUnload` is called before `dealloc`, and then crash due to selector sent to deallocated view controller.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: er, I just got it for the first part right after I posted this problem. I used controller's view property as [view removeFromSuperview] which loads the view if it's not in the memory. Using [controller isViewLoaded] will solve it.

Comment: I read the doc and I noticed that access of view property will cause the view being loaded, but. I wish the doc hightlight this as much a possible, lol

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly normal behaviour. `viewDidUnload` is called in a low memory situation to notify your controller that the view has been released.

There's a clear outline of the steps in the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1).

Specially, look at the steps detailed in the section [Understanding How Views Are Loaded and Unloaded](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html), where it covers the unload cycle:

> 1. The app receives a low-memory warning from the system.
> 2. Each view controller calls its didReceiveMemoryWarning method. If you override this method, you should use it to release any memory or
>      objects that your view controller object no longer needs. Do not use
>      it to release your view controller’s view. You must call super at some
>      point in your implementation to ensure that the default implementation
>      runs. The default implementation attempts to release the view.
> 3. If the view cannot be safely released (for example, it is visible onscreen), the default implementation returns.
> 4. The view controller calls its viewWillUnload method to inform subclasses that the views are about to be removed. A subclass
>      typically overrides the viewWillUnload method when it needs to save
>      any view properties before the views are destroyed.

and so on.

In your specific case, you definitely **don't** want to release the view controller in this case. If there's any further memory management you want to do whilst there's low memory, you should override the default implementation of [didReceiveMemoryWarning](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didReceiveMemoryWarning). As the docs state, don't forget to call `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`.

Comment: Side note `viewDidUnload` is deprecated since iOS 6.